# invalid token authentication

Tags: java, azure, token, adal

I follow the guide on this URL for acquire a azure accessToken.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-java-native-headless

I'm able to acquire the token both accessToken and idToken.
In result I can also access to user info.
But when I'm going to use the access Token for query graph I have unauthorized access ( 401 ) .

Also if i use the same accessToken from Postman is the same.

Comment: What the `query graph` means? If you do the same as the guide, and do other operations,  I suppose you did not grant the other permission. In the guide, it just grants the `User.Read` permission.

Comment: Do you have any update about this thread?

Answer (score 0):

According to the guide, it just grants the **user.Read** permission, so you could get the user info with token.

If you want to access other graph resource, you need to grant the other delegate permisson.
We could get the premissions information from the corresponding [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/v1-overview).

Take [get user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_get) API for example at least `User.Read` is required. If you want to access **other** Microsoft Graph API, we need to know what permission is needed. If possible, you could add the related information into the question.

How to add the delegate permissons, please refer to this screenshot

[image]